# Change height of parent div based on height of child div with absolute position

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a simple slideshow I use to flip through advertisements for a community site. I'm new to jquery so I'm not sure how to change the height of the parent div based on the child div that the jquery pulls next. See the below jsfiddle for my code.

HTML:

```
<div class="slideshow" id="ads_slideshow">
  <div id="slide1" class="slide">
    <p>Test Advertisement</p>
    <p>Just testing advertisements</p>
  </div>
  <div id="slide2" class="slide">
    <p>Test Ad 3</p>
    <p>One more test ad, just for clarity.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slideshow{ position: relative; border: 1px solid #000; }
#slide1, #slide2{ position: absolute; }
```

Jquery:

```
$(function () {
    $('.slideshow div').hide();
    $('.slideshow div:first-child').show();
    setInterval(function () {
        $('.slideshow div:first-child').fadeOut(500)
            .next('div').fadeIn(500)
            .end().appendTo('.slideshow');
    },
    2000);
});
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/us3m9/4/

Comment: Forgot to mention. I got the jquery code from a different question and changed it to fit my needs. I'm just stumped on changing the parent div based on the current content that isn't hidden.

Comment: Will the contents inside the div be the same height?

Comment: No, they can range from just a few lines of text to text and an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did:

Basically, I took the height of the slide that is currently shown and set the height of `.slideshow` to that height.

http://jsfiddle.net/8fTfX/

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    $('.slideshow div').hide();
    $('.slideshow div:first-child').show();
    $('.slideshow').height($('.slideshow div:first-child').height())
    setInterval(function () {
        $('.slideshow div:first-child').fadeOut(500)
            .next('div').fadeIn(500)
            .end().appendTo('.slideshow');
        $('.slideshow').height($('.slideshow div:first-child').height())
    },
    2000);
});
```

CSS: (added transition because why not?)

```
.slideshow {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    transition: height 500ms;
}
#slide1, #slide2 {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: I'm changing my accepted to yours since the jquery is cleaner and the transition is more appealing. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
place this code :
-------------------------------

 $(function () {
     // height of the div
     var ht = $(".slideshow .slide").height();
     $(".slideshow").css("height",ht);

      $('.slideshow div').hide();
      $('.slideshow div:first-child').show();
      setInterval(function () {
        $('.slideshow div:first-child').fadeOut(500)
        .next('div').fadeIn(500)
        .end().appendTo('.slideshow');
         // height of the div
          var ht = $(".slideshow .slide").height();
         $(".slideshow").css("height",ht);         

      },
    2000);
});
```

js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/us3m9/7/